# SQL query select list where first and last letter arnt

Tags: mysql, sql

please see the Q on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-11?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

regarding an sql query:

> Query the list of CITY names from STATION that either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

So far I have got

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
    WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE'^[aeiouAEIOU].*$' 
   AND city NOT LIKE '%a' 
   AND city NOT like '%e' 
   AND city NOT like '%i' 
   AND city NOT like '%o' 
   AND city NOT like '%u'
```

and it is telling me this is wrong but I cant see any wrong answers in the output please advise....
thanks

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a challenge to **do it yourself**?

Comment: A hint: should `Chicago` be in your result or not?

Answer (score 0):

Helo, it worked in my tests.
Try to compose your regular expression.

Not begins AND not ends with wovels:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY  NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*'
AND CITY NOT RLIKE '.*[aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

Not begins OR not ends with wovels:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY  NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*'
OR CITY NOT RLIKE '.*[aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

Not begins XOR (OR exclusive) not ends with wovels:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY  NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*'
XOR CITY NOT RLIKE '.*[aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

Hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using MySQL:

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]' OR CITY NOT RLIKE '[AEIOUaeiou]$' GROUP BY CITY;
```